# "no implicit conversion of Array into String" when trying to parse JSON data

Tags: arrays, json, ruby-on-rails-4, type-conversion

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I’m trying to parse JSON data, so I have

```
content = ["{\"sEcho\":3,\"timestamp\":1464705752942,\"iTotalRecords\":1242,\"iTotalDisplayRecords\":1242,\"aaData\":[{\"externalId\":\"4279\"}]}"]
my_object_times_array = JSON.parse(content)
```

Sadly, the second line gives the error

```
no implicit conversion of Array into String
```

The JSON is well-formed (at least as far as I can tell) so I’m not sure what is causing the error above and how to fix it.  I would prefer not to change the JSON.

Comment: try:
my_object_times_array = JSON.parse(content[0])

Comment: Uhm codepen is Javascript, !NOT RUBY! Are you trying to solve the problem with JS or RUBY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content` is an array, but JSON.parse expects a JSON String.

**Example of usage from the documentation:**

```
require 'json'

my_hash = JSON.parse('{"hello": "goodbye"}')
puts my_hash["hello"] => "goodbye"
```

[Check the documentation here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse)

**So you could do following**:

```
content = "{\"sEcho\":3,\"timestamp\":1464705752942,\"iTotalRecords\":1242,\"iTotalDisplayRecords\":1242,\"aaData\":[{\"externalId\":\"4279\"}]}"
my_object_times_array = JSON.parse(content)
```

or

```
content = ["{\"sEcho\":3,\"timestamp\":1464705752942,\"iTotalRecords\":1242,\"iTotalDisplayRecords\":1242,\"aaData\":[{\"externalId\":\"4279\"}]}"]
my_object_times_array = JSON.parse(content[0])
```